# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException - Unknown column in field list

Tags: java, sql, web-applications, jdbc

I am getting the following error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'userId' in 'field list'

The code which is causing this error is this:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = 
    con.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO " + 
        tableName + 
        " (userId,username,email,password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
```

My table gets created by the following command

```
stmt.executeUpdate(
    "CREATE TABLE " + 
    tableName + 
    " (" + 
    " userId INT, " + 
    " userName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, " + 
    " email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, " + 
    " password VARCHAR(255), " + 
    " PRIMARY KEY(userId)" + 
    " )");
stmt.close();
```

Can someone help me spot my mistakes if any. I am a novice in this so I am kind of struggling to find where exactly the error is.

Comment: Does `tableName` contain the value you expect it to at the moment you prepare the statement?

Comment: Your error shows that "i" in the column name userid is small. Shouldnt it be capital?

Comment: @ShashankKadne MySQL column names are not case sensitive, though table names often are. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: yes. I tried to print out the value of tableName before I called the prepare statement. It had the correct value.

Comment: Did you verify that the create statement actually succeeded? That you didnt have, perhaps, a table already with the same name in the database, but with different columns?

Comment: @ShashankKadne I think when I copied it here I made the I mistake. In reality, the error has capital I. Sorry about that

Comment: can you show your set statements?  pstmt.setInt()..., pstmt.setString()... etc

Comment: @Perception your guess was right. There was another user table which was causing this error. Now I got rid off all tables and the statement doesn't throw an error anymore. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The error was because there already existed another table with the same table name.

Comment: This answer is same with @Perception comment?

Comment: @IswantoSan yes. It is. But I didn't know how to tag Perception to it. Anyway, I upvoted his answer.

Answer (score 1):

One other thing to look at is triggers.  I was getting the same error and eventually determined that the error was the result of a trigger statement rather than the insert statement.  The "unknown column" was in a table the trigger was trying to insert into.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using insert statement and there is **column value missing or empty**. It can give this error. I was using prepared statement. I got this error for a column having numeric data type. The root cause of this was empty string being passed as column value. Strangely it throws "unknown column" e